# Self Join in SQL

Tags: sql

I have an Employee table with few records in it, from which I want to get all the employees who work in the department where employee "scott" works and those with department number as 20.

Comment: what database engine and what have you tried?

Comment: Sharing a sample dataset helps form the query.. Also, share what you have tried and where you are stuck

Comment: School assignment? Show us some sample table data, the expected result and your current query attempt!

Comment: @Manoj Desai, Please go through the link to learn how to ask a good question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

can you give a try on the following query and let me know if this worked for you

```
select * from employee where deptno in (select deptno from employee where name ='scott')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very Descriptive, But u may try this as per the Information u've provided,

```
Create Table #Employees
(Id int,
EmpName nvarchar(20),
Deptno int
)

Insert into #Employees Values(1,'Henry',10)
Insert into #Employees Values(2,'Mark',20)
Insert into #Employees Values(3,'Scott',20)
Insert into #Employees Values(4,'David',10)
Insert into #Employees Values(5,'Peter',30)
Insert into #Employees Values(6,'Mary',20)
Insert into #Employees Values(7,'John',30)


Select EmpName From #Employees
Where Deptno In(Select Deptno from #Employees Where EmpName = 'Scott')
```

> And for Complete information of Employees,

```
  Select * From #Employees
  Where Deptno In(Select Deptno from #Employees Where EmpName = 'Scott')
```

Answer (score 0):

For example the following query returns employee names and their manager names for whom they are working. Copy & Paste the following sql, I think it may help the purpose.

```
Create table Emp
(

empid int primary key,
name varchar(50),
mgrid int
)

Insert into Emp(empid,name,mgrid)

values (1001,'Manish Agrahari',1001); 

Insert into Emp(empid,name,mgrid)values (1002,'Deepti',1001);

Insert into Emp(empid,name,mgrid)values (1003,'Amit',1001);

Insert into Emp(empid,name,mgrid)values (1004,'Sandy',1002);

Insert into Emp(empid,name,mgrid)values (1005,'Ankit',1003);

Insert into Emp(empid,name,mgrid)values (1006,'Kapil',1002);
```

Run The following SQL and see the result:

```
SELECT e.empid, e.name, m.name  "Manager" FROM Emp e, Emp m WHERE e.mgrid=m.empid;
```